# Flutter firebase stream with dynamic document id/path

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app where I use a StreamProvider in main.dart like so:

```
          ...
          StreamProvider(
          catchError: (context, error) {
            print(error);
          },
          initialData: null,
          create: (context) => _quizService.getCurrentQuestionStream()),
          ...
```

In the app I have a collection called QuizQuestion, each document has a date as it's id, like `2021-12-15`, and so every day the app should fetch the QuizQuestion of the day. My stream function looks like this:

```
  Stream<QuizQuestion> getCurrentQuestionStream() {
    String currentDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());
    try {
      return _firebaseFirestore
          .collection("QuizQuestion")
          .doc(currentDate)
          .snapshots()
          .map((doc) => QuizQuestion.fromJson(doc.data()));
    } catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

This works to get the current day's QuizQuestion, but if the user has the app open from one day to the next, the stream function is still "subscribed" to fetch the previous date, since it won't define the `currentDate` variable again. I'm trying to figure out how to solve this, is is possible to some how to listen on a day change in flutter to reinitialize the stream with a new date, or do I need to rethink the backend here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change an existing query. You will have to construct a new query for the new date.

There are two common ways to do this:

- Track the current date in your application code, and construct the new query once you detect the new date there.
- Write the current date to a fixed location/documentation in the database, e.g. `qotd` for question/quiz of the day. You could for example do this when you also write the quiz for the next day. Now have your application listen to that document, and when you detect a change in the document, load the quiz for that day.

Both are valid options, and you can  embed either option into a stream of your own, which you then feed to the stream builder. I typically prefer the latter as it also gives me a way to control what quiz(es) can be read through security rules.